# How do you disable automatically copying text when pasting over it in visual mode in VS Code?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, vscode

Like the title says, if I have yanked some text, then select what I want to replace in visual mode, press `p` to paste, I want the original text still available to paste in other locations.  I never want to paste the replaced text or have to remember to use registers in this case.

This is related to [Clipboard is reset after first paste in Visual Mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25259/clipboard-is-reset-after-first-paste-in-visual-mode) but the solutions there don't apply to VS Code as far as I can tell.

How do you configure the VS Code vim plugin to do this?

Comment: Why do you need a solution that can't use a critical/primary feature of vim (registers)? If you can drop that restriction there's this: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25259/clipboard-is-reset-after-first-paste-in-visual-mode?rq=1 (You can create a mapping or macro so the register use happens transparently.)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I’ve closed this as a duplicate. If you don’t find your answer in the linked post, please [edit] your question to clarify why it’s not a duplicate.

Comment: To be clear: is the issue that VS Code (w/ vim plugin) doesn't have registers? Most of the solutions there involve the use of registers